# Modular form not meromorphic at $\infty$

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, modular-forms

Is there a function $f$ with the following properties

1. $f$ meromorphic at the upper half plane  $\mathfrak h$,
2. $f$ is of weight $k$ under a congruence subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$,
3. $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$.

Modular forms or functions are defined to have good behaviour at $\infty$. But I have not seen an example showing that this is a necessary part of the definition.

Comment: $e^j \varphi$ where $j$ is the $j$-invariant and $\varphi$ is any form of weight $k$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[expanding on my comment to convert it to an answer]

An example is $e^j \varphi$ where $j$
is the $j$-invariant and $\varphi$ is any nonzero form of weight $k$.

In general a holomorphic (or meromorphic) function on the upper half-plane
that is invariant under ${\rm SL}_2({\bf Z})$ is the same as an entire
holomorphic (or meromorphic) functon of $j$.  So for $k=0$ all we need is a
entire function (or a meromorphic function on $\bf C$) that is not a
polynomial (or rational) function.  The exponential is a simple example;
there are plenty of others, including functions such as $\tan j$
which has infinitely many poles in each fundamental domain.

Comment: Also I think that for $k=12 a+b,4\le b\le 14$ the weight $k$ level $1$ modular forms with any kind of singularity at $i\infty$ are of the form $\Delta(z)^a G_b(z)f(j(z))$  with $f$ entire.

Comment: Almost: $b$ must be even, it doesn't quite work for $b=12$ 
because the Eisenstein series $G_{12}$ has a zero in each fundamental region.
So say $b \in \{0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14\}$ and declare that $G_0 = 1$.
(Also, the OP allowed modularity under a congruence subgroup of 
${\rm SL}_2({\bf Z})$, and those get harder to describe once the
associated modular curve has positive genus.)

Comment: Yes obviously I messed up with $b=0,12$. For the level $n$ and weight $0$ case: the coordinate ring of $\Bbb{\Gamma\backslash H}$ is a free $\Bbb{C}[j]$ module $\sum_{l=0}^r h_l \Bbb{C}[j]$. Is $\sum_{l=0}^r h_l Hol(j)$ integrally closed? If so:  $Hol(\Bbb{\Gamma\backslash H})$ is integral over $Hol(j)$ and we'd get $Hol(\Bbb{\Gamma\backslash H})=\sum_{l=0}^rh_l Hol(j)$.